# Bash assign output/error to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have the following line in my bash file:

`LIST=$(ssh 192.168.0.22 'ls -1 /web');`

The problem I am having is that it is a part of automated script and I often get this on the `stdout` and not the data I need:

`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

I realize that `LIST` only gets the `stdout` of the `ls`. So I am looking for a command that would get more of the info from the commands. In particular:

- `stdout` for `ls` - I have that right now
- `stderr` for `ls` - not really interested, I don't expect a problem there
- `stdout` for `ssh` - Not interested, I don't even know what it would output
- `stderr` for `ssh` - **THIS IS WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR** to check whether it `ssh` correctly. This being empty should mean that I have the data in `$LIST` I expect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From ssh man page on Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS):

```
EXIT STATUS
     ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.
```

Knowing that, we can check exit status of `ssh` command. If exit status was `225`, we know that it's an `ssh` error, and if it's any other non-zero value - that's `ls` error.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

TEST=$(ssh $USER@localhost 'ls /proc' 2>&1)

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    printf "%s\n" "SSH command successful"
elif [ $? -eq 225   ]
    printf "%s\n%s" "SSH failed with following error:" "$TEST"
else 
    printf "%s\n%s" "ls command failed" "$TEST"
fi
```

Comment: OK, but now I don't have the `stdout` of the `ls`, and I need that.

Comment: @PatrickKusebauch  Does your `ssh` connection produce error simultaneously with `ls` producing output ?  If not, what's going to be stored in the variable is either `ssh`'s `stderr` or `ls`'s `stdout`

Comment: OK, how do I differentiate then?

Comment: @PatrickKusebauch  You could check `$?`  variable. If there was an error, it would be equal to non-zero value.  I'll add example in a moment.

Comment: `$?` will also be non-zero if the `ls` fails.

Comment: I don't mind that. I have clear differentiation when I have the correct data from the `ls` and when something went wrong.

Comment: @PatrickKusebauch  I think Kusalananda's solution so far is better. I'll delete my answer for now, but  I'll repost if  manage to edit into a better form

Comment: Actually I like yours better. It works for both commands error and does not use a file. But What do I know... :)

Answer (score 3):

Redirect `ssh`'s standard error to a file within the command substitution and then test to see whether the file is empty or not:

```
output="$( ssh server 'command' 2>ssh.err )"

if [[ -s ssh.err ]]; then
    echo 'SSH error:' >&2
    cat ssh.err >&2
fi

rm -f ssh.err
```

which displays `SSH error:` followed by the captured error output from `ssh`.

Comment: IIRC the double quotes around process substitution  aren't necessary when assigning to a variable. They're only necessary to avoid word splitting when process substitution is passed as argument to another command.

Comment: @Serg According to Stéphane Chazelas (whom I trust quite a bit on these issues), one should always double quote variable expansions, command substitutions, and arithmetic expansions (unless there is a particular reason not to, I assume, and there seldom is).  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/116858

Comment: @Serg You might be correct when it comes to assignments, but I don't want too many rules to keep track of, so I double quote anyway. It doesn't hurt.

Comment: Ad 2nd solution: I don't want the error to be displayed directly. I want to have control when and how I display the error.

Comment: @PatrickKusebauch So, my first alternative does exactly that. Just `cat` the `ssh.err` file whenever you want to, if its size is non-zero (tested with the `-s` test as in my code).

Comment: @Serg is right http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131784

Comment: @StevenPenny Yes, but after 25 years at the command prompt, I'd still be more inclined to take Gilles' and Stéphane's advice and _always_ quote expansions. Especially when writing answers here.

Comment: I agree they are both brilliant, but the simple fact is that you 3 are all wrong in this case

Comment: @StevenPenny Not wrong. It may be unnecessary to quote a command substitution, but it's definitely not _wrong_.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember some variant must work. Try this:

```
cmd 2>>>$errmsg
```

triple redirect possibly... It was many years ago...
in variable errmsg must be output error message. Maybe I am wrong. In this case this variant get message 100% guarantee:

```
errmsg=`cmd 2>/dev/null`
```

This variant suppress error message while need it to out or may be not need. But usual output it catch also. So you may distinct those two cases by $? value and correct your script.